# Sword Collision timing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

So I made a sword collision script that enables a animation and triggers the box collider on, is there anyway to add a timer to the animation and extended time for the Box collider.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    Collider Col;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Col = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", true);
        else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", false);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        Col.enabled = true;
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        Col.enabled = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't understand from your question what you are trying to do. Please explain in more detail what you mean.

Comment: So when I am attacking the box collider only appears when the left mouse button is down, the second I let go the collider does not collide anymore, i'm trying to find away so that if you click left mouse button the collider turns on for a certain time frame, and turns off after that time frame

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coroutines to perform operations outside of the Update Loop.

```
float enableColliderForSeconds = 1f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Col.enabled = false; //in case it is enabled from a canceled Coroutine
        StopCoroutine(Collider()); //canceling Coroutine first to not stack
        StartCoroutine(Collider());
    }
}

IEnumerator Collider()
{
    Col.enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(enableColliderForSeconds);
    Col.enabled = false;
}
```

You should probably work out what you are really trying to do in more detail, because this really isn't applicable to a proper game mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to separately track how long the collider has been active, and after that time is over disable it.

There are many ways to do that, here's a simple example:

```
    Animator anim;
    Collider Col;

    float colliderAppearTime = 1.5f;
    float colliderTimeRemaining = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Col = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Col.enabled) {
            colliderTimeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (colliderTimeRemaining <= 0) {
                Col.enabled = false;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            anim.SetBool("Attacking", true);
            Col.enabled = true;
            colliderTimeRemaining = colliderAppearTime;
        }
    }
```

When the fire button is pressed, we enable the collider and reset the `colliderTimeRemaining` variable to how long we want it to stay - in this case we use the `colliderAppearTime` variable which is set to 1.5 seconds.

Then, every frame, we check if the colider is enabled. If it is, we decrease the `colliderTimeRemaining` by the frame time `deltaTime`, and when it reaches 0, we turn the collider off.

Comment: So this will be a seperate Script tracking the main attack script correct?

Comment: No this replaces your own script from the question. Instead of setting it on/of when the player presses or releases the button - you set it on when the player presses the button, and turn it off after a certain time has passed

Comment: Ok thanks its works, just the animation is looping but I can fix that

Comment: Ok thank you this fixed everything, I just added an extra part to the script to tell the animation to stop when I let go of the button but that's all I had to fix everything is working fine.